# Numeric Keys in containers.map error

Tags: matlab, key, containers

I have a containers.map object in MATLAB where the keys are numerical. The code is as follows:

```
a = containers.Map('KeyType','int32','ValueType','char');
a(1) = 'abcd';
a(2) = 'fds';
a(3) = 'sdfa';
```

Now, say I want to remove keys 1 and 2 (and their values) from the map. I simply write

```
remove(a,[1 2])
```

But I receive the following warning

```
Warning: The specified key is not present in this container.
```

The key/value pairs are not removed from a. Why are the keys not found?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Instead of deleting my question, I figure I'd post my answer.

The problem seems to be that MATLAB wants one to specify the keys using a cell array. The following code works:

```
remove(a,{1 2})
```

I suppose the code in the original question was telling MATLAB to look for the key (vector) [1 2]?

Comment: @Ratbert It's telling me I need to wait 2 days to accept my own answer.